# Links in job matches email are not https yet

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, email, ssl

Three links in the email sent with new jobs matches are still not https:

> [image]

1. Stack Overflow logo, links to http://stackoverflow.com/
2. "See more jobs", links to http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&q=
3. "Send us your feedback", links to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

All the rest (i.e. links to the actual job page and "Manage job alerts") are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report! We're currently undergoing a large email project that will see all of these emails go through an overhaul, including making all link consistently HTTPS. We're expecting to deliver that to prod in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: "next couple" is 6-8... Thanks anyway! ;-)